# MongoDB is giving inconsistent write times

Tags: mongodb, reactivemongo

I am using Scala, Reactive Mongo 0.10.5 and Mongo 2.6.4 running on Ubuntu.  I have tested on a few machine configurations but right now I am working with 15gb of memory, 2 cores and 60gb of SSD storage (AWS)

I have just set up a test mongo instance and have been using it to benchmark a few things, however I am seeing some inconsistency that I can't explain.

I am writing a consistent amount of data using 10 separate threads to a single collection.  Each write consists of a document containing an array which contains 1000 elements.  Each element is a complex document consisting of several fields and nested fields.  I have tested with arrays of 1000, 10000 and 100 and have seen the same behavior with all.  Each write is unique (i.e. I never write to the same document twice)

The write speed tends to be around 100-200ms per write with the current hardware I am using.  I would like better but that isn't my main issue.

My main issue is that sometimes the write times will spike.  When they do, it can take a single write several seconds to complete.  They do eventually complete but it takes a while.  I have timeouts built into the app doing the writing (10 seconds) and when the spikes happen it will frequently hit that timeout.  I have increased the timeout and verified that the write does eventually complete but it can take a long time (30+ seconds).

I have worked with Mongo before using the Mongo Java Driver in Scala and have not noticed this problem.  However it is unclear whether the issue is a result of the driver, or my Mongo setup.

I have looked at the logs and while they report when the query is taking longer, they don't actually provide any information about why it is taking longer.  I have done the same with profiling and again they report a long query but don't say why it is long.

I have run mongostat while running and it seems that when the writes start taking a long time I notice a similar slow down in mongostat.  I.E. mongostat will pause for several seconds before continuing.

The mongo machine itself is bored while this is happening.  Load averages are minimal as are CPU and memory usage.  It does not appear to be going into swap.

I suspect I just have something configured incorrectly in the Mongo but I haven't been able to find anything that indicates what.

Has anyone seen this behavior before?  Is it something in my configuration or perhaps something with the Reactive Mongo driver?

## UPDATE:

Using iostat I was able to determine that the normal writes/second is hitting around 1Mb/second.  However during the slow periods it spikes to 6-7Mb/second.

I also found the following in the mongo logs.

> [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took 15621ms  for 35 files
>
> [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took 14816ms  for 22 files

In at least one case this log statement corresponds exactly with one of the slow downs.

This definitely seems to be a disk flush problem based on these observations.

Does this imply that I am pushing more data than the current Mongo configuration can handle?  Or is there some other configuration that can be done to reduce the impact of those flushes?

Comment: Any possibility that your slowdowns are caused by a flush to disk? Why dont you add your setup to MongoDB MMS and take a look at all the graphs it provides for you -- background flush times among them.

Comment: Take a look at IO with iostat or something similar. What's your driver configuration (including the journaling setting)?

Comment: It could be caused by flush to disk.  But is such an extreme slowdown expected by such a flush?  Is there anyway to smooth it out?  I.E. is it possible to make it flush more often so that each individual flush has a smaller impact?  Going from a few hundred millis to several seconds is a pretty big performance hit.

Comment: It seems clear from your update that the issue is the disk flush overwhelming the disk. Try looking at the [production notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/production-notes/) and [EC2-specific  configuration notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/) to see if there are any tips there that help. For example, the readahead settings are not set optimally for MongoDB by default.

Comment: I have modified the read ahead settings as well as setting the noatime flag for the disks.  Those settings don't seem to have made any noticeable difference.

Comment: While I have not specifically fixed this, I have alleviated the symptoms somewhat by moving the journal files to a separate disk and reducing the size of the data being written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in this case the problem may actually have been related to thread locking within the application itself.  Once I resolved the issues with thread locking these other issues seemed to go away.

To be honest I don't know why thread locking would result in the observed behavior in Mongo, but if the problem is gone I am not going to complain.